# How to keep vertex labels in plot in python igraph

Tags: python, igraph

I have an igraph

```
g = igr.Graph([(0,1), (0,2), (2,3), (3,4), (4,2), (2,5), (5,0), (6,3), (5,6)])
g.vs["name"] = ["Alice", "Bob", "Claire", "Dennis", "Esther", "Frank", "George"]
g.vs["age"] = [25, 31, 18, 47, 22, 23, 50]
g.vs["gender"] = ["f", "m", "f", "m", "f", "m", "m"]
g.es["is_formal"] = [False, False, True, True, True, False, True, False, False]

layout = g.layout("rt")

g.vs["label"] = g.vs["name"] #assign each node label to the name
color_dict = {"m": "blue", "f": "pink"} #create a colour dictionary
g.vs["color"] = [color_dict[gender] for gender in g.vs["gender"]] #apply dictionary to each node
visual_style = {}
visual_style["vertex_size"] = 20
visual_style["vertex_color"] = [color_dict[gender] for gender in g.vs["gender"]]
visual_style["vertex_label"] = g.vs["name"]
visual_style["vertex_label_dist"] = 1
visual_style["vertex_label_angle"] = 3

visual_style["edge_width"] = [1 + 2 * int(is_formal) for is_formal in g.es["is_formal"]]
visual_style["layout"] = layout
visual_style["bbox"] = (400, 400)
visual_style["margin"] = 20
visual_style["vertex_label_angle"]=0
igr.plot(g, **visual_style)
```

[image]

but the vertex labels are out of the plotting area. ie Frank is cut off.
Is there a way to ensure that all of the labels stay within the plot area?

I tried adjusting (as per manual (adjust distance from centre and rad angle))

```
visual_style["vertex_label_dist"] = 1
visual_style["vertex_label_angle"] = 3
```

to no avail.

I also tried running different layouts, but often a vertex label will be printed out of the plotting area.

Any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Adjust

```
visual_style["margin"] = 20
```